# Create a diagram larger than A4

Tags: app.diagrams.net

How can I create a diagram larger than A4 in draw.io?

Is there a specific trick?  I've tried menu items.  Do I need to register for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background pages are just drawn as you set shapes down on the respective areas. Just drop something outside of the page area, the new background will appear.